# How to set the correct Visual Studio version as JIT debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have VS2003, VS2005 and VS2008 installed on my machine.

The C++ application is compiled with VS2005 but when it crashs and i select debug the
Just-In-Time Debugging dialog comes up and only offers me 
"New instance of Visual Studio .NET 2003".

Debugging a 2005 compiled program with 2003 is not possible.

If i attach the process to VS2005 then it works well, but this is very inconvenient.

How do i set .NET 2005 vor JIT debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay i found it. BTW installing VS2003 after VS2005 kills all others JIT debuggers, this was the reason for the problem.

From Visual Studio menu , select "Tools->Options->Debugging->Just-In-Time" and then check "Managed", "Native" and "Script".